# the opposite of projection

Tags: general-topology

Please feel free to edit this question - I am decidedly rusty and probably inaccurate on my mathematical terminology :-)

I am familiar with the notion of projecting points from some space $\mathbb{R}
^n$ to another $\mathbb{R}^m$ where $m<n$, but am interested in what holds if $m>n$.

Suppose I have two non-intersecting and simply connected sets of points $C_1$ and $C_2$ defined over $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now suppose I "extend" the vector defining any point in either set into $\mathbb{R}^m$ by injecting an appropriate number of arbitrary scalars into the vector. Will the set of all possible extensions of this kind of $C_1$ remain non-intersecting with all possible extensions of $C_2$ so long as the "extension" is made on the same basis - scalars are injected at the same positions in each case? That is my intution from $\mathbb{R}^1$, $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I'd like to be sure this holds as one moves into higher dimensions.

Also, am I correct that in a simply connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists at least one path which will connect any point in that set to any other point in that set via a path comprising points only from that set? And will this property of simple connectedness potentially be lost if one "extends" to higher dimensions? It seems to me that one can't say anything at all about the connectedness after this kind of extension.

Comment: I think the property of $C_1,C_2$ you are describing is called path-connectedness, and that $C_1 \cap C_2$ is not path-connected.  If you allow arbitrary "extension" to $\mathbb{R}^m$ of these sets, such that they project onto $C_1,C_2$, it is possible that path-connectedness of the higher dimensional sets is lost "depending on how the sets are extended", as you say.  Is there more of a Question involved?

Comment: OK - clear misunderstanding occurring, so let me edit the question.

Comment: Do you inject arbitrary scalars only at the end of the vector, or anywhere in between? If the latter, then the disjoint simply connected sets $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ in $\mathbb R^1$ have intersecting extensions $\{(1,y):y\in\mathbb R\}$ and $\{(x,2):x\in\mathbb R\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Good point. I knew there was a reason I didn't become a mathematician - lack of precision :-) Any extension/insertion of extra values into the vectors always occur at the same place. So $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ can only ever be extended to $\{x,1\}$ and $\{y,2\}$ or to $\{1,x\}$ and $\{2,y\}$.

Comment: You are using [the phrase "simply connected"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space), which is a stronger condition than path-connected.  Is it so intended?

Comment: Yes - I edited the question to de-emphasise the role that paths play. Nonetheless, I'm still interested in the connectedness or otherwise of these sets. The sets are projections from a higher dimension, and certain properties hold once projected. I'm interested in what properties hold in the original dataset - disjointness between the sets most importantly, but connectedness wihtin the sets too if there is anything useful that can be said about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter $\pi$ is often used to denote a projection map, so let $\pi:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be projection onto the first $n$ of $m$ coordinates.  The situation would be equivalent if some other subset of size $n$ of $m$ coordinates were chosen.

Consider a "lifting" of two (path-)connected subsets $C_1,C_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ to *m*-dimensional subsets that project back to $C_1,C_2$ respectively.  That is, suppose there are functions $f_i:C_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\pi \circ f_i$ is the identity on $C_i$.

Now we are requiring a 1-to-1 correspondence between $C_i$ and its lift $f_i(C_i)$, though without requiring continuity of the functions $f_i$.  In this situation $f_i(C_i)$ need not be connected even if we require $C_i$ to be connected, or path-connected, or even simply connected (the strongest of the three conditions).

For example, let $C_i$ be an interval restricted to the first component of $\mathbb{R}^n$, say $[i,i+\frac{1}{2}] \times \{0\}^{n-1}$.  Define $f_i(r,0,\ldots,0)$ by inserting $m-n$ trailing coordinates using $1$s if $r$ is rational and $0$s otherwise.  Then $f_i(C_i)$ is not connected, even though $C_i$ is as nicely connected as one can ask.

The other issue raised by the Question is whether disjointness of $C_1,C_2$ is necessarily preserved by their lifts $f_1(C_1),f_2(C_2)$.  The answer is yes, and there's a simple argument involved.  Suppose for contradiction that $x \in f_1(C_1) \cap f_2(C_2)$.  Then what of $\pi(x)$?  As $x \in f_i(C_i)$, we must have $\pi(x) \in C_i$ for both $i=1,2$.  But this contradicts the disjointness of $C_1,C_2$.

Comment: Thanks - I think that confirms my intutions that (a) the lifting/extending of the sets preserves their disjoint nature and that (b) and connectedness could be preserved or destroyed, but it totally depends on the nature of the lift - or in this formulation, on the continuity of the lifting function.